# iOS Nocilla expect a request to have a header

Tags: ios, kiwi, nocilla

I'm using [Nocilla](https://github.com/luisobo/Nocilla) along with [Kiwi](https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi) and I need a test that verifies that the my network client correctly sets given a HTTP header to the request under certain circumstances. How can I do that?

cheers,
Jan